# Making all instances of a class share one value - Audioclips

Tags: java, class, audio

In my game, I have a class called "Sound", which that creates a new audioclip with the given filename. e.g.

```
Sound mining = new Sound("mining.mp3");
```

Recently I have implemented a mute button but I want the mute button to mute /all/ sounds effects. I have made a static variable mute, but it seems to get muted for all sounds in that class.

To elaborate, there is a class called **"WindowHandler"**, which handles all the UI buttons, the buttons all have sounds, if I mute one of the buttons all of them are muted. But in a seperate class **"PickUpRock"** which needs the mining sound effect, this is /not/ muted.

How should I be changing the value of the mute variable? Right now I'm just calling

```
sound.setMute(true)...
```

Is there a general method for saying like

```
allSounds.setMute(true)?
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the variable in the `WindowHandler`, or `Sound` class?

Comment: The mute variable? It's a static variable in the sound class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a global instance of Sound and replace all of your local Sound(s) with the global Sound.
That way, when you mute it, everything is muted, rather than just one class.